# Guest User unable to upload file from flow

Tags: visual-workflow, guest-user, screen-flow

I have a flow where the guest user can upload a file and attach it to a case. The flow works in our development environment, but not in testing or production. As a guest user if the file is uploaded I get the error message: "Can't upload File.csv." or whatever filename I use. So my assumption is that it has something to do with the environment of the org. The problem is that there is another flow that is engineered a bit differently but guest users are able to upload files just fine. And I believe this flow worked at one time.

I have checked to make sure that Settings -> General Settings -> "Allow site guest users to upload files" is checked.

I couldn't find any triggers, validation rules, or classes affecting any of the following: Content Version, Content Document, Content Delivery, or Content Document Link.

Any other ideas of what the problem could be or where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: did you look here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/313421/2602 (the reassign new records to default owner check box?). Also [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_files_best_practices.htm&type=5) and [here](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAxhNAAS/file-upload-screen-component-in-flows-will-not-work-for-guest-users-after-secure-guest-user-record-access-and-assign-new-records-are-enabled)

Comment: Yes. I couldn't find an option to disable it. I assumed it was part of the recent security updates on Guest Users. I have the guest records reassigned but there is no checkbox near there or anywhere else that I have seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the association, in the backend, the documentID is null somehow in the same transaction so contentdocumentlink throws error when it tries to create that record.

Solution: in the flow where there is a relatedrecord id field: don't associate any record id like accountid,case id whatever. Let it be blank. The user will be upload the file but association will not happen.
We can achieve this association by creation one assignment (text collection) and store all the contentversion IDS from the file upload. loop over them and fetch all the contentdocumentIds and store them in a other collection. Then loop over contentdocumentIds and create a ContentDocumentLink record where linkedentityid is your object id where this files will be associated to(like account id) and contentdocumentId will be the ids from the contentdocumentIds collection. Then create one "create element" for object ContentDocumentLink and create records in one go. All the files will be uploaded and mapped correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is your situation but I have had this happen to me

Hypothesis - It is a race condition

- Transaction (1) The Case xxxxx by  guest user was created at T(0)
- Transaction (2) The case assignment rules execute - by definition, these execute asynchronously for Community Users. Until they execute, the case is owned by the Community User (before becoming owned by Support). They finished executing at T(2)
- Transaction (3) The file upload attempt was made at T(1). Some automation executes that causes the Case to be updated while it is still owned by the guest user (assignment rules haven't finished executing) and consequently the file upload fails

My solution was to coerce in the quick action used by the Guest User the Case Owner to be a non-guest user (e.g. the `Support` queue) - this way, when the case was created it never was owned by the guest user

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I have left the upload screen up, checked the case that was created and made sure it was assigned, went back and clicked the upload button and still had the error.

Comment: oh well; did you check the debug log under the guest user to see how far in the file upload process you got?

Comment: I don't have access to the debug logs on the testing site. However, I created a debug log for the guest user on my development site. I couldn't find where the file was uploaded. The case was created. I clicked on the file upload button and chose the file. But there was nothing in the debug log after the case was created.

Comment: so - if there's no flow or trigger on CV, CD, or CDL, there won't be a debug log. Add a do nothing before insert /update trigger on these objects in your dev environment and you might get a glimpse at the underlying error. If the triggers never appear in the debug log; then you know that it is the guest user / external user permissions at the most fundamental level that blocks file uploads

Comment: Got it. Thanks I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't disagree with the earlier answer, but I think there may be a simpler option.

**TL;DR** you want to leave the files your user uploads in the screen flow as "orphaned" Content Document files, then you'll create your target object record (the record you want the files to be related to), and then you'll use a loop to create a JUNCTION ContentDocumentLink record for each "orphaned" Content Document file that was uploaded by the user in the screen element.

**I just built a solution for this exact requirement and I:**

1. In the "File Upload" screen input component I stored the Content Document IDs into a text collection variable (configure this in the "Advanced" settings of the File Upload component) **LEAVE THE "Related Record ID" parameter BLANK**
2. After my screen element, I used the CREATE records element to create the target object record that I want to relate the files to.
3. After creating the target object record, I setup a loop that iterated through the text collection variable that stored all the Content Document IDs from my File Upload screen component.
4. add an Assignment element in your loop to populate TWO LOOKUP FIELDS
   on a record variabl required to create the junction record
   ContentDocumentLink: 1) LinkedEntityID and 2) ContentDocumentID (you may
   need to populate other fields for your use case see [documentation here]
   [1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)) 4a)the ContentDocumentID is the record Id of the Current Content
   Document record in the loop that came from your File Upload component. 4b)
   the LinkedEntityID is the ID of the target object record you created in
   step 2.
5. In your step 4 assignment element, below the two lookup field assignments add one final assignment where you ADD the record variable to a record COLLECTION variable (for object ContentDocumentLink).
6. At the end/outside of your loop, add a CREATE records element - create multiple records using the record collection variable from your loop.

[Here is a link to the tutorial video](https://www.loom.com/share/ee1c199ebefd47739fc459aec4ff97bd?sid=65fdb946-03e2-4c9f-b62d-e8ddc58ce416) I recorded of how I built everything and all the little details.